# Error Handler in VBA 2016

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have read through the multiple Q&As on error handling in VBA but for some reason my code does not work. I am trying to filter for a specific word (variable name "item"), if the filtered range does not have the word, it must skip the code and jump to error handler (and go to the next word). This must be continued until the for is done. My code is below:

```
Sub Group_Button1_Click()

    Worksheets("Grouping_Name").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    lastrow_grouping = Selection.Count + 1


Dim filterRange As Range
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim lastrow_To_be_grouped As Long

For grouping_counter = 2 To lastrow_grouping

'   on to_be_grouped sheet turn off any autofilters that are already set Sheets("To_be_grouped").AutoFilterMode = False
'   find the last row with data in column A of To_be_grouped sheet
lastrow_To_be_grouped = Sheets("To_be_grouped").Range("A" & Sheets("To_be_grouped").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'   the range that we are auto-filtering (all columns)
Set filterRange = Sheets("To_be_grouped").Range("A1:B" & lastrow_To_be_grouped)
 '   Copy filtered data (exclude header) in To_be_grouped sheet
Set copyRange = Sheets("To_be_grouped").Range("A2:B" & lastrow_To_be_grouped)

 '   Assign variable "item" which is the word to filter
Item = Sheets("Grouping_Name").Range("A" & grouping_counter).Value
 '   Filter column with variable item
filterRange.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="=*" & Item & "*", Operator:=xlAnd

 '   copy the visible cells to Final_Grouping sheet
 '   determine first row with no data in Final Grouping sheet and copy to sheet
On Error GoTo errorhandler
' This is where I need help, if there is no line with the filtered word the code must jump to errorhandler
If IsNumeric(copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count) = True Then
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Final_Grouping").Range("A" & item_counter_total)
'   delete the tables
Sheets("To_be_grouped").Range("$A$1:$B$" & lastrow_To_be_grouped).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _
(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

' Count the number of rows added
item_counter = copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count / 2
'  ------------------------------------------

For group_table_counter = item_counter_total To item_counter_total + item_counter - 1 Step 1
   Sheets("Final_Grouping").Range("C" & group_table_counter).Value = Item
Next group_table_counter
 '  ------------------------------------------
item_counter_total = item_counter_total + item_counter
End If
errorhandler:
Next grouping_counter
End Sub
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: why do you need an error handler?  Couldn't you change your IF logic to be something like If copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 0 then ...Granted, this hasn't been tested, but should do the same thing, right?

Comment: also, to clarify a bit: IsNumeric(copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count) = True  will always be TRUE because the count you're returning is 0, which just so happens to be a number...

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what your code is doing exactly or what the error that you are trying to capture is, but one of the problems you are having is that you can't put "Next grouping_counter" in the error handler.

I think your misunderstanding is based on the fact that if you put in an "On Error GoTo ErrorHandler" statement, the code in the ErrorHandler will be run in the case of an error.

But when the code is compiled, VBA is trying to determine whether the code makes sense and is giving you an error that there is no For Loop for your next statement, because, while if an error were to occur where you expect it to, you would be within a for loop, the program is not aware of this.

As sous2817 mentioned in a comment, you likely do not need error handling here, but I will present both methods so you can better understand how to do error handling.

In this case, you could use ErrorHandling in a couple of ways, assuming that an error occurs in your code:

1.

```
For grouping_counter = 2 To lastrow_grouping
    'some code here

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    'code that has error you are trying to handle
    'more code to run
NextGroupingCounter:  'label to jump to from error handler

Next grouping_counter


Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

     GoTo NextGroupingCounter

End Sub
```

Of course, this is if you don't actually want to do anything with the error other than skip the rest of the code.  If that is what you want, then just change the On Error Code to GoTo the NextGroupingCOunter label!

2.

```
For grouping_counter = 2 To lastrow_grouping
    'some code here

    On Error GoTo NextGroupingCounter
    'code that has error you are trying to handle
    'more code to run
NextGroupingCounter:  'label to jump to from error handler

Next grouping_counter
```

Of course, you likely don't even need the error handling

3.

```
For grouping_counter = 2 To lastrow_grouping
    'some code here
    If [*insert text to check condition needed for no error*] Then
             'code to run if no error
    End If
    'If the condition needed for no error is false, this will just go to the next one.
Next grouping_counter
```

Option 3 is preferred if possible.  If an error will actually occur in your code, then Option 2 will work fine.  If you want to capture the error and then jump back into your loop, Option 3 works.

Additionally, notice that I put "Exit Sub" above the ErrorHandler.  The ErrorHandler label is just a label, so if the program runs until the end, it will run the code in the ErrorHandler section.  The Exit Sub ends the procedure to avoid this.

Also note that for other circumstances, you could use "On Error Resume Next" to just continue in the case of an error or even put "Resume Next" in your error handler to return to the line after the one of error.  This is a bit beyond the scope of the question, but may add some useful info.